# nextjs getting warning about case sensitive filenames

Tags: javascript, macos, webpack, node-modules, next.js

Was initially using lowercase filenames in my nextjs app on my Mac but changed to uppercase to match filename standards. After I did this, I keep getting this error below

Tried deleting `.next` and `node_modules` folders and reran npm install but still got the same error and I think it might be because nextjs compiles the files to lowercase

[image: lowercase filenames]

I have also tried following the instructions with this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin but still facing the same issue as well

```
[ info ]  ready on http://localhost:3000
[ warn ]  ./pages/Flashcard.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-babel-loader.js??ref--4!/Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/pages/Flashcard.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-babel-loader.js??ref--4!/Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/pages/Flashcard.js
* /Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-babel-loader.js??ref--4!/Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/pages/flashcard.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/bubba/Desktop/ui-projects/ui/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2Fworkout&absolutePagePath=%2FUsers%2Fbubba%2FDesktop%2Fui-projects%2Fui%2Fpages%2Fworkout.js&hotRouterUpdates=true!
```